# Splidejs autoplay not working on first view on svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

i tried to create image slider using splidejs on my svelte app, the slide is working but when i tried to apply autoplay config, the slide is not working at first or when i open the page with splidejs instance in it, but when go to another page and then back to that page (page with splidejs instance in it) the slide is works fine with autoplay.

here my splide component code

```
<script>
    import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
    import {onMount, afterUpdate} from "svelte";
    import {generateId} from "../functions.js";

    export let id = "sliders-" + generateId(5);
    export let perView = 1;
    export let perTouch = 1;
    export let autoplay = false;
    export let type = 'slide';
    export let interval = 5000;
    let rendered = false;
    let refresh = false;
    let sp;

    onMount(function(){
        sp = new Splide( '#' + id + '.splide', {
                type: type,
                rewind: true,
                autoplay: autoplay,
                interval: autoplay ? interval : 0,
                perPage: perView,
                perMove: perTouch,
                focus: "center",
                drag: true,
                cover: true,
                height: '250px',
                trimSpace: false,
                arrows: false,
                pagination: true
            }).mount();
        
    });
</script>

<div id="{id}" class="splide">
    <div class="splide__track">
        <div class="splide__list">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have tried another solution such as using svelte-slide package from npm, using another package such as glidejs but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to integrate this kink of component is to use "actions" : https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action

```html
<script>
   import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
 
   // options & co

   function sp(element) {
     new Splide(element, { /* options */}).mount()
   }
</script>

<div use:sp/>
```